# Read Nested JSON and insert into DB

Tags: json, hibernate, api

I have a json input like below

```
{
   "SdAff”: {
      "userId": " svc_gen_nsm ",
      "id": "IFMS12345",
      "additionalaffecteditems": [
   {
      "itemType": "NODE-ID",
      "ItemName": "22BT_ORNC03",
      “restoreTime”: ” 25-JUL-2018 14:11:48”
   },
   {
      "ItemType": "CCT",
      "ItemName": "A_circuit_id",
      “restoreTime”: ” 25-JUL-2018 14:11:48”
   },.....]   

         }
    }
```

The additionalaffecteditems can have multiple values. And I will have read the values one by one and insert them into DB using hibernate.

My entity class name is SdAff where I have the DB mapping for each item. Can someone suggest how to accomplish this.

Thanks !!

Comment: Use **Jackson** library to handle JSON. Here (https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial) is the tutorial.

Comment: I have created a seperate class which contains the setter and getters for itemtype,itemname and restrotetime and I am putting this as an arrayList in my main POJO class. But how to iterate through this arrayList to get the vaues.